# Koma Script handbook says chapters can start on any page using headings=openany?

Tags: sectioning, lyx, chapters, koma-script, scrbook

On page 87 of THE GUIDE: Koma Script [2015-1-14] under the section "Structuring of Documents" the guide lists many "options" for changing the default output of `\chapter` sectioning, such as `headings=big` and `headings=openany`.  There are a great many options listed throughout the document for various things, and I don't understand where to implement them in LaTeX markup.  (I'd like to shrink the Chapter Title down from Huge to Big, and have it open a new chapter on any page, rather than just right side pages)

I tried in the Preamble, and that failed, and also I tried as option in, for instance `\chapter[headings=openany, headings=big]{The Big Vacation}` but that just replaces the chapter title with an optional title for the table of contents, in Koma Script.

Where does the options and values listed in the Koma Script document belong within LaTeX markup?  I'm using LyX by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how this can be done in LyX, but those are options to be passed to the document class.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[headings=openany,headings=big]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{The Big Vacation}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

BTW: if you want to reduce the size of headings titles you have to use `headings=normal` and not `headings=big` which is the default.

If you prefer to declare them in the preamble you can use `\KOMAoptions`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{headings=openany,headings=big}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{The Big Vacation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, and I was also able to get it to work in LyX using the drop down menu: Document>Settings>[Document Class] then typing into the Class Options/Custom field: headings=openany,headings=big

Comment: @user12711 Glad to help. :-)